# Punching power and Incline bench pressing

Tags: weightlifting, boxing

So it feels like to generate strong punching power you'd need starting strength, high RFD, and good limit strength. General exercise + Plyometrics, Westside , vand dyke style training or triphasic training, contrast should work very very well for that. But I read an interesting thing by Waterbury and always wondered if he was right. 
http://chadwaterbury.com/should-you-bench-press/

(An immediate counter example would be Shane Carwin if I'm not mistaken, who mostly bench presses).

He says that since you retract your scapula when benching, it neglects the serratus anterior and the transfer/efficiency of transfer to the mechanics of a punch are subpar.

Also wondering about overhead pressing, eventually very explosive, as a carry over towards punching, since it's a rather different plane of movement.

Comment: Power punching happens when well coordinated technique engages the legs, core, torso, shoulders and finishes with the extension of the fist. Any of the exercises you talk about focuses more on what would be considered "arm punching," which is always going to be weaker and less effective than engaging your body.  It's a lot like a power pitching motion.  Classic baseball power pitchers like Seaver, Ryan and Clemens got their power mostly from the drive from their lower body, not their "arms."

Comment: Related: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7523/what-are-the-primary-muscles-worked-when-hitting-a-heavy-bag/7524#7524

Answer (score 1):

At first bench press, incline bench press looks OK. However you need coordination, as @PoloHoleSet mentioned, but also punch is kind of explosive, while bench pressing is rather maximum power exercise. Static vs dynamic. If your gym has landmine attachment put one end of barbell, and throw other end, catch with opposite hand. Like in [this film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wai8-UP9H4w). Be sure to use whole body. Later, you can do some feet movements.

Problem with this exercise is that you are moving catching hand back, and then punching. During the fight that is clear signal what is going on.